# Android App Giving Error - Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

The App Starts and works fine for minutes 10 - 20 minutes then it randomly closes and gives in the Application output

Here is the log:

```
[mono-rt] Stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.wrapper_native_0x408027e9 (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00026, 0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.NewGlobalRef (intptr) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:514
[mono-rt]   at Java.Lang.Object.RegisterInstance (Android.Runtime.IJavaObject,intptr,Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership,intptr&) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Object.cs:179
[mono-rt]   at Java.Lang.Object.SetHandle (intptr,Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Object.cs:166
[mono-rt]   at Java.Lang.Object..ctor (intptr,Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership) [0x00036] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Object.cs:87
[mono-rt]   at Android.Views.IWindowManagerInvoker..ctor (intptr,Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-15/src/generated/Android.Views.IWindowManager.cs:969
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___intptr_int (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0005e, 0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&) <IL 0x00030, 0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (object,object[]) <IL 0x00007, 0x00097>
[mono-rt]   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.DoInvoke (object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo) <IL 0x00099, 0x003b3>
[mono-rt]   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo) <IL 0x00007, 0x00087>
[mono-rt]   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke (object[]) <IL 0x00015, 0x000db>
[mono-rt]   at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateProxy (System.Type,intptr,Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership) [0x00059] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Interop/TypeManager.cs:271
[mono-rt]   at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateInstance (intptr,Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership,System.Type) [0x001ea] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Interop/TypeManager.cs:249
[mono-rt]   at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject (intptr,Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership,System.Type) [0x000ba] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Object.cs:333
[mono-rt]   at Java.Lang.Object._GetObject<T> (intptr,Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership) [0x0001a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Object.cs:313
[mono-rt]   at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<T> (intptr,Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Object.cs:305
[mono-rt]   at Android.Views.IWindowManagerInvoker.GetObject (intptr,Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-15/src/generated/Android.Views.IWindowManager.cs:950
[mono-rt]   at Java.Interop.JavaObjectExtensions._JavaCast<TResult> (Android.Runtime.IJavaObject) [0x001de] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Interop/JavaObjectExtensions.cs:98
[mono-rt]   at Java.Interop.JavaObjectExtensions.JavaCast<TResult> (Android.Runtime.IJavaObject) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Interop/JavaObjectExtensions.cs:50
[mono-rt]   at Android.Runtime.Extensions.JavaCast<TResult> (Android.Runtime.IJavaObject) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/Extensions.cs:11
[mono-rt]   at FlyOutMenu.DensityExtensions.ToPixels (Android.Content.Context,int) [0x0000c] in /Users/ashnil.narayan/Downloads/MenuCopyEdit Test/FlyOutMenuMainTestMain/FlyOutMenu/FlyOutContainer.cs:294
[mono-rt]   at FlyOutMenu.FlyOutContainer.DispatchDraw (Android.Graphics.Canvas) [0x00040] in /Users/ashnil.narayan/Downloads/MenuCopyEdit Test/FlyOutMenuMainTestMain/FlyOutMenu/FlyOutContainer.cs:264
[mono-rt]   at Android.Views.View.n_DispatchDraw_Landroid_graphics_Canvas_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-15/src/generated/Android.Views.View.cs:8794
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.ca00081b-bb14-464b-92e7-3f392b1bd24c (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00043>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.ca00081b-bb14-464b-92e7-3f392b1bd24c (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00023, 0xffffffff>
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
[mono-rt] a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
[mono-rt] used by your application.
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] 
[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)
```

But this is also there

```
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
[mono-rt] a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
[mono-rt] used by your application.
[mono-rt] =================================================================
```

I have no idea what is going on? Any Help Will be Great

Comment: Can you try and be more specific with your question? Does it always happen? Are you doing a specific thing when it crashes? If you launch your app and leave it there will it do the same thing? Does it always take 10-20 min?